# Can I convert HL7 v2 message to a FHIR resource directly?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Currently we are doing some POC around converting HL7 v2 message to a FHIR resource.

So as a first step we are converting the HL7 v2 message into an XML format using XMLParser from HAPI API, and as a second step we have written an XSLT to convert this XML into FHIR Resource XML format.

So I just wanted to figure out whether there is any simpler approach to do this HL7 v2 to FHIR resource conversion as a one step process rather than the two steps that I just spoke about.

Answer (score 4):

There's no canned process. The core problem is that segments are not naturally identified, and resources must be (that's the core of the RESTful part). And identifying segments usefully is a business problem - it must be done based on the contents of the segment, it's context in the message, and local identification etc practices applicable to the source of the message

So what this means is that there's no canned code. I've published some javascript that works in a particular environment, but is useful as an illustration:

http://www.healthintersections.com.au/A31ToPerson.js

There's also http://bit.ly/14rgaWS

Answer (score 3):

One of the best tutorials that I found about this topic is: [HL7 v2 to FHIR Interface Mapping](https://medium.com/@awatson1978/hl7-v2-to-fhir-interface-mapping-f83c6ecf6bee), from the author "Abigail Watson".

Assuming you will use the [HAPI TestPanel](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/hapi-testpanel/index.html) as the HL7-v2.x EHR, that will be sent to the [NEXTGEN CONNECT INTEGRATION ENGINE](https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/NextGen-Connect-Integration-Engine-Downloads) that makes the conversion from HL7-v2 to JSON, and then is sendt to the [Meteor on FHIR Interface Engine](https://github.com/clinical-meteor/meteor-on-fhir).

Additional information about mappings can be found on the manual of the NEXTGEN(Or "MIRTH" the old name.) [HL7 v2.x to FHIR Conversions](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/HL7+v2.x+to+FHIR+Conversions).